Stray (orphaned) nodes remain after queue_free() of their parent scene
Godot 4.2.1
I have implemented a simple scene-save system:


The Savegame Autoload listens for the S key press.

When S is pressed, the Savegame Autoload makes an array of ALL the nodes inside Main. This is recursive, i.e. it accounts for children, children-of-children, etc.

Once the array of ALL the nodes inside Main is made, it sets the owner of every Node inside to Main.

Then, the Main Scene is packed (using pack(Main)).

The PackedScene is saved to the disk using ResourceSaver.save(), making a node-perfect copy of the game state.

Main is finally unloaded using Main.queue_free().


Code:
print("SAVE START")

var allNodesInMain = get_childrenRecursively(Main)
for node in nodes:
    node.owner = Main

var packed_scene = PackedScene.new()
var result = packed_scene.pack(Main)

print(str(result))
if result == OK:
    var error = ResourceSaver.save(packed_scene, FILE_PATH)
    if error == OK:
        print("Saved packed scene")
    else:
        print("An error occurred while saving the scene to disk.")

Main.queue_free() #Unload the main and free the RAM

This works fine, it's very easy to implement, saves the state of EVERYTHING inside the game, and I intend to use it as a "save-load game" system.
However, I've noticed that once the Main is freed (and the screen turns gray), the Debug Monitor shows that the game still has 50 Orhpaned objects. Printing those objects using Savegame.print_orphan_nodes() shows that some of the Nodes inside the Main (now unloaded) are still being kept in memory! And not some exotic, programmatically-added Nodes — the basic "Wall", "Enemy1", "Powerup1" Nodes. This obviously introduces a memory leak (of about 2MB) that accumulates the more the game is saved-loaded.

How come some Nodes are kept (and become stray) after technically the ENTIRE scene containing them has been unloaded using queue_free()?

Is the Main Node an Autoload?

@liggiorgio The Main node is not an autoload - just manually added control-type node. In the code I used a shorter denomination (just main) instead of an actual "GAME.mainScene" which is the variable inside the GAME autoload that stores the reference to Main node

Why are you queue_free()ing the Main node inside the savegame method? What happens next? Are you perhaps loading the scene you just queued for deletion right after?

@liggiorgio Hi, Sorry for the very late update. The reason for unloading the main is to simulate the load process. I.e. player saves the game, then loads the game. Loading the game needs to erase the Main node ("clean slate"), then load the saved scene. That is my logic.

@liggiorgio Also, I did the following to narrow the problem down: Delete some node in editor, Start game, Save, Load, see if orphans appear.  Seems like some code in certain node (haven't exactly identified which) causes orphaning. Any common rookie mistakes that cause orphans to appear (or rather get created on instantiating complex scenes like the saved "Main")?

The answer is: This looks like a bug. You should log it here: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues
There is a larger design discussion about whether or not you should be blowing away your main node. Without seeing your project, it's hard to tell. But I suspect that this bug is happening because you are freeing everything. If the process that frees nodes is multi-threaded, it's possible for your main node to think all its children have been told to destroy themselves, but then kill itself before that happens, and because all the threads are running off the main node, they get told they're done and die without doing their job. This is just a theory.
My recommendation is twofold:

Log the bug on GitHub.
Rename you Main node to something like Game, and then have a Main node that its sole job is to save and load the main node and provide the interface to do that.

If you're already doing the second step, we're back to: this is a bug that should be reported.
